# How can i download a file to my server, from another ftp server

Tags: php, download, permission-denied

I am a realtor/web designer.  I am trying to write a script to download a zip file to my server from a ftp server.  My website is all in php/mysql.  The problem that I am having is that I cannot actually log in to the ftp server.  The file is provided through a link that is available to me, but access to the actual server is not  available. Here is the link i have access to.

ftp://1034733:ze3Kt699vy14@idx.living.net/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ftmyersbeach_data.zip

php's normal functions for accomplishing this give me a connection error.  Php does not have permission to access this server...  Any solutions to this problem would be a life saver for me.  I am looking to use a cron job to run this script every day so i don't have to physically download this file and upload it to my (godaddy) server, which is my current solution (not a good one, i know!).

Also, I can figure out how to unzip the file myself, as I have done some work with php's zip extension, but any tips for an efficient way to do this would be appreciated as well.  I am looking to access a text file inside of the zip archive called "ftmyers_data.txt"

Comment: Are you really sure your script is using the same connection properties (I guess you are ;-) )? Do you have a static IP? Maybe the target server is restricting connections for this user to your IP.

Comment: Can you show your attempt at using the PHP FTP tools?

Comment: The php FTP tools that i know of seem to all require a username and password.  I don't have any login information for the ftp server.  I only have this link.  I'm also not sure about the IP stuff, but I don't think it would matter in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have shell access to the server on which your PHP application runs? If so, you might be able to automate the retrieval using a shell script and the ftp shell command.

Comment: Thanks Guys.  I do have shell access, although I haven't used it yet.  And the curl solution gives me an empty zip file.  I tried a similar curl script before as well.  I'm thinking that I need a creative workaround to get this done!

Comment: I figured it out!  Looks like shell access was the way to go!  Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0):

Use php_curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
$fh   = fopen("file.zip", 'w');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://1034733:ze3Kt699vy14@idx.living.net/idx_fl_ftp_down/idx_ftmyersbeach_dn/ftmyersbeach_data.zip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
fwrite($fh, $result);
fclose($fh);
curl_close($curl);
```

Easy as pi. :)

Comment: This only gives me an empty zip file :<

Comment: use shell access if anything goes wrong it will print errors that will help you out.

Comment: I'm attempting to use shell access and wget, however I keep getting a 'connection refused' problem.  I can download the file with wget on my local machine, but am having no luck with it on godaddy's servers. (which would be my hosting plan).  Please help!

Comment: It means that either your firewall or the other server's firewall is blocking you.You could however be banned by them.